# How do I write a ExtensionFunctionDefinition in saxon 9.5?

Tags: xslt, saxon

The [example usage of ExtensionFunctionDefinition](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/integratedfunctions/ext-full-J.html) from the saxon documentation does not compile with Saxon version 9.5.1-6

The error I get is:

```
java: <anonymous ShiftLeft$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method call(net.sf.saxon.expr.XPathContext,net.sf.saxon.om.Sequence[]) in net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionCall
```

How do I make this code compile in Saxon 9.5?

```
private static class ShiftLeft extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition {
    @Override
    public StructuredQName getFunctionQName() {
        return new StructuredQName("eg", "http://example.com/saxon-extension", "shift-left");
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes() {
        return new SequenceType[] {SequenceType.SINGLE_INTEGER, SequenceType.SINGLE_INTEGER};
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType getResultType(SequenceType[] suppliedArgumentTypes) {
        return SequenceType.SINGLE_INTEGER;
    }

    @Override
    public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression() {
        return new ExtensionFunctionCall() {
            public SequenceIterator call(SequenceIterator[] arguments, XPathContext context) throws XPathException {
                long v0 = ((IntegerValue)arguments[0].next()).longValue();
                long v1 = ((IntegerValue)arguments[1].next()).longValue();
                long result = v0<<v1;
                return Value.asIterator(Int64Value.makeIntegerValue(result));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseTransformerFactory;
import com.saxonica.config.ProfessionalConfiguration;
import com.saxonica.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Value;
import net.sf.saxon.expr.XPathContext;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionCall;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionDefinition;
import net.sf.saxon.om.Sequence;
import net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator;
import net.sf.saxon.om.StructuredQName;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException;
import net.sf.saxon.value.Int64Value;
import net.sf.saxon.value.IntegerValue;
import net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceType;

import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringWriter;

class ShiftLeft extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition {
    @Override
    public StructuredQName getFunctionQName() {
        return new StructuredQName("eg", "http://example.com/saxon-extension", "shift-left");
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes() {
        return new SequenceType[]{SequenceType.SINGLE_INTEGER, SequenceType.SINGLE_INTEGER};
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType getResultType(SequenceType[] suppliedArgumentTypes) {
        return SequenceType.SINGLE_INTEGER;
    }

    @Override
    public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression() {
        return new ExtensionFunctionCall() {
            @Override
            public Sequence call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments) throws XPathException {
                long v0 = ((IntegerValue)arguments[0]).longValue();
                long v1 = ((IntegerValue)arguments[1]).longValue();
                long result = v0<<v1;
                return Int64Value.makeIntegerValue(result);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Very sorry, the documentation is out of date. Wojtek's answer is correct. I'll raise a bug to get the documentation fixed.